# Control Azure Container-Level Access Policy with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I am trying to design a Java application running on a local server that manages the access permissions to blobs that are being stored in Windows Azure.  The cloud storage resources are used by several mobile applications (also written in Java) that need read access, and sometimes temporary write access, to a single blob container hosted in the cloud.  I am using the [Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java by Microsoft Open Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694271.aspx).

My question is:  How (or if) container-level [stored access policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee393341.aspx)  in Azure can be made to revert to an earlier stored policy (READ) on expiration, rather than to “no access. “

The MSDN article: [Creating a Shared Access Signature in Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh875756.aspx) provides a good start, but it doesn’t yet say much about how to use container-level stored policies to manage shared access polies with Java .  I am learning Java and SAS, and because I was unable to find Java code examples similar to [Access Control for Azure Blobs](http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/access-control-for-azure-blobs/),  I have included a short piece of Java code below to demonstrate my question.

The server application retrieves the private storage connection string used to connect to Azure storage. Gets the cloud storage account and creates a cloud blob client. Gets a reference to the container and creates a container if it does not already exist. (Note that a container name must be lower case.) It then downloads the current permissions for the container. (Up to five container-level stored access policies may be saved for a container.)

For example, let's say there are two stored access policies, named "baxter" and "heath," controlling the container-level permissions, and that both policies were set to READ (only) when the stored access polices of the container were previously saved.  These initial policies, with READ permissions, are set to expire after several months.   Mobile applications assigned to either the "heath" or "baxter" policies then start out with read-access to blobs stored in sascontainer6 through uri strings similar to:

```
http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net/sascontainer6/image4.jpg?sr=c&sv=2012-02-12&sig=5G7EOgiYYNEGmw2Y0T4IUgt%2FzTnmYpaxWfB5nEira08%3D&si=baxter

http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net/sascontainer6/image4.jpg?sr=c&sv=2012-02- 12&sig=llUoAg2PvFUfhO28ncrlheh2RRJdb7smQEX6nO8xoCk%3D&si=heath
```

As needed, the server application can elevate a subset of mobile applications to both READ and WRITE permissions without having to issue a new string.  It can do so by modifying the "baxter" policy saved with the container. The ‘granularity’ of the control is at the policy level, and the policy update enables all the mobile applications assigned to the "baxter” policy to write (or overwrite) blobs in the container.  Mobile applications assigned to the "heath" policy continue to have READ (only) permission. In a similar way, the server application could revoke all access to the container for applications assigned to a particular policy.

Before changing the policy, the server application ensures that public access to the container has been turned OFF. It specifies the current time as the start time and an expiration time for access that is one hour after the start time. It sets both the READ and WRITE permissions for the new policy. Finally, the existing "baxter" policy is overwritten with the new policy.

The generateSharedAccessSignature method can get a shared access signature (SAS) for the "baxter" and "heath" policies. Changing the permissions saved in the policy should not alter the SAS, and applications using the above uri strings should work until the specified expiration time.

However, once the expiration time is reached, the “baxter” string will lose all permissions to the container, both READ and WRITE. But this is not what I want to happen.  I need the permissions for mobile applications assigned to the “baxter” policy to revert back to READ (only.)   Because a SAS string with WRITE access enables anyone to write to the resource, the best practice is to keep the period between start time and expiration time as short as possible, no more than an hour. Setting the permissions to READ for longer periods is acceptable for my particular application.

My question is:  How (or if) container-level shared access policies in Azure can be used to allow the token (i.e. the “baxter” string shown above) to revert back to an alternate policy (i.e. READ) rather than “no access.”

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException 
    {           
    Account creds = new Account();              
    final String storageConnectionString = creds.getstorageconnectionstring();
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("sascontainer6");
    container.createIfNotExist();
    BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = container.downloadPermissions();
    containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.OFF);
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    policy.setSharedAccessStartTime(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(calendar.getTime());
    policy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE));
    containerPermissions.getSharedAccessPolicies().put("baxter", policy);            
    container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);
    String sas = container.generateSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(),"baxter");         
    String sasex = container.generateSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(),"heath");         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You demonstrate good understanding on the Container Level Access Policies along with SAS. All explained leads to the very specific question:

> My question is: How (or if) container-level shared access policies in
>   Azure can be used to allow the token (i.e. the “baxter” string shown
>   above) to revert back to an alternate policy (i.e. READ) rather than
>   “no access.”

Which' answer, unfortunately is **NO**. You can't define a `fallback` for what happens when container level policy expires. Once it expires, it's over, done. No SAS associated with it can do any action over the resources associated. You have to, from your server side code to explicitly overwrite it again with new permissions and new expiry date.

But I want to challenge your conceptual architecture a bit. You have a statement:

> As needed, the server application can elevate a subset of mobile
>   applications to both READ and WRITE permissions without having to
>   issue a new string.

Even if your `server` does so, how do the mobile clients understand that now they can also `write`, rather than only `read` from that cloud storage? I really doubt that your mobile clients always try to write silently die if they can't.

My guess is that there is some kind of `server-to-mobile-client` communication before the mobile client is aware that it can write to the cloud storage. If there is no such communication then something is terribly broken IMHO.

However, if such communication exists, then nothing will stop you from providing a new shorter living SAS with `RW` permissions (Read and Write). This new shorter living SAS can even be a `stand alone` SAS, meaning that it is not associated with any stored Access Policy, and is issued specifically for the reason of writing to the blobs.

My other guess is that you want to avoid sending SAS over the wire to avoid `man-in-the-middle` type attacks. And rather want to have the SAS pre-configured in the application. If this is the case, I can suggest to have separate Access Policies for Read and Write. You can safely have an `expired` Access Policy for writing, and make it valid only when needed. Your device will have now 4 SAS URIs instead of 2, but it (the device) will know precisely which policy is Read Only, and using which can attempt writes. Note that even expired, the Write access policy is still associated with the container, it is not removed. So you just need to update it the next time you want it to be active.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and thoughtful response. Your answer confirms what I encountered in my tests - a url incorporating an expired SAS (associated with a policy or not) stops working (no access) and does not 'fallback' to any permissions at all - not even the specified public access level. The client needs a different url. Yes, I am trying implement container-level control while having to pass a minimum number urls. As you suggest, I'll probably go with multiple container-policies so that I can reactivate/revoke the url strings as necessary. - Thanks!